# How can I use a regular expression to compare one field to another?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the rows where the size in the title does not correspond correctly to the width and height. See how in the title column it shows something like "11x14" or "16x20", but the width and height should basically be switched? I am trying to find these rows so I know which ones to fix.

```
nid     width   height  title
4702676 14      11      Black V Groove 11x14
4702682 20      16      Red V Groove 16x20
```

This is what I have tried, but it returns a result set like this (the first row should not be there):

```
nid     width   height  title
4702674 11      14      White/Tan 11x14
4702676 14      11      Black V Groove 11x14
4702682 20      16      Red V Groove 16x20

SELECT nid, width, height, title  
FROM my_table
WHERE CONCAT(field_rm_width_value, "x", field_rm_height_value) != title  REGEXP '^(\d)*x(\d)*'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT nid, width, height, title  
FROM my_table
WHERE title like(CONCAT('%',height,'x',width))
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
SELECT nid, width, height, title 
FROM `my_table`
WHERE title NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', width, 'x', height)
```

Select all rows where the the title doenst finish with the combination of width and height values